# get mesh/face/vertices count in BabylonJS outside of the inspector

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I would like to be able to show some basic stats for my scene in BabylonJS, without needing to display the [inspector](https://doc.babylonjs.com/toolsAndResources/tools/performanceProfiler). Is there a way to get those statistics from the scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can thanks to the scene instrumentation class:

`var instrumentation = new BABYLON.SceneInstrumentation(scene);`

Documentation: https://doc.babylonjs.com/divingDeeper/scene/optimize_your_scene#sceneinstrumentation

For mesh / faces / vertices count:

```
scene.getTotalVertices(); // total vertices
scene.getActiveIndices() / 3; // faces
scene.getActiveMeshes().length; // Total meshes
```